# Querying the row of an ADO.NET sql database given the value of its first column (C#, Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, ado.net

My C# skillset is very limited. My code background is MATLAB, FORTRAN, and more recently, Python. I've used Xamarin in visual studio to bootstrap a smart device application for a quick demonstration internally.

Elsewhere in this application I create a SQLite database with ADO.NET, and populate it with entries the user selects from pickers, spinners, and text entry. Each row is a 'profile' for that person.

Now, another portion of the app takes the first column (Profile Names) and populates a spinner such that a user can select themselves thusly:

```
    //Check if database exists and get rider names for selection
        bool exists = File.Exists(pathToDatabase);
        string nameString = string.Empty;
        if (exists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Reading database");
            var connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + pathToDatabase);
            connection.Open();
            using (var contents = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                contents.CommandText = "SELECT [Name] FROM Riders";
                var r = contents.ExecuteReader();
                while (r.Read())
                    nameString += (r["Name"].ToString() + ",");
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        //Populate spinner with Rider Names
        string[] nameList = nameString.Split(',');
        var ridernameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, nameList);
        ridernameAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        RiderSelectSpinner.Adapter = ridernameAdapter;
```

This works great, the names appear in my spinner, and the user can select them.

The reason I'm here, is I want to now get all the rest of the data in that row associated with the profile when they select themselves, given the value of the first column (the name).

I have all the code that recognizes when they select themselves. Can someone guide me in forming a query in ADO.NET that gets the rest of the row given the first row entry? Something like below?

```
                contents.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Riders WHERE [Name] = @Name"; //FIX
                contents.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Just select all needed columns with your first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, path); 
var resunt = conn.Table<Riders>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name); //Using LINQ or
```

or

```
var conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(plat, path);     
var resunt = conn.Query<Riders>("SELECT * FROM [Riders] WHERE [Name]=" + name);
```

Comment: Best practice would be using a parameterized query instead of String concatenation.